# Multi database search and update

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I don't know where I made a mistake. My goal is to get 1 database of data and transfer it to another database. In doing this, I must use table 2.

[image]

Query:

```
UPDATE [VSRO_SHARD].[dbo].[_RefObjChar] 
SET ID = (SELECT ID 
          FROM [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_RefObjChar] 
          INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT Link 
               FROM [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_RefObjCommon] 
               WHERE CodeName128 LIKE 'MOB_RM%') 
         ) 


Update
U
Set
U.ID = O.ID
From MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable AS U
INNER JOIN MyDatabase2.dbo.MyTable2 AS O ON U.ID = O.ID
INNER JOIN MyDatabase2.dbo.MyTable3 AS K ON U.ID = K.Link
Where 
K.CodeName128 like '%%'
```

Problem solved.

INNER JOIN requires AS and ON. Thx @Barmar

Comment: `INNER JOIN` requires an `ON` condition to specify the relationship between the tables.

Comment: You should also have a `WHERE` condition in the `UPDATE` statement, otherwise it will update ALL the rows in the table.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to use where in the update. I also get an error when I uninstall the INNER JOIN app

Comment: `set ID = (...) WHERE someColumn = someValue`. Replace `someColumn` and `someValue` with the appropriate condition to specify which row should have its ID changed.

Comment: I never said to remove INNER JOIN, I said you need to add an `ON` clause to indicate how the `Link` relates to a column in `RefObjChar`, so it can find the matching row in the two tables.

Comment: It should be `ON Link = someColumnFromRefObjChar`

Comment: It seems like you need to study a SQL tutorial.

Comment: @Banner Yes i think i need to review a tutorial don't know how to edit this query. And sory for my bad English